# using curl via Indy in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, curl, delphi-xe2, indy

I am trying to use IdHTTP to equivalence this curl operation (known to work) in Delphi XE2:

```
 curl http://hub.Healthdata.gov/api/action/datastore_search --data-urlencode '
 {
  "resource_id": "391792b5-9c0a-48a1-918f-2ee63caa1c54",
  "filters": {
    "provider_id": 393303
   }
   }'
```

I have tried the following code, but it does not work ... can someone advise as to correct procedure?
It replies bad request.  Thank you.

```
procedure TfrmMain.get1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  lParamList: TStringList;
  result:string;

begin
  lParamList := TStringList.Create;
  lParamList.Add('"resource_id": "391792b5-9c0a-48a1-918f-2ee63caa1c54"');
  lParamList.Add('"filters": {"provider_id": 393303}');

  lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    Result := lHTTP.Post('http://hub.Healthdata.gov/api/action/datastore_search --data-urlencode ',
     lParamList);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(lHTTP);
    FreeAndNil(lParamList);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

The `--data-urlencode` parameter is not part of the URL, it merely tells curl how to encode the data being posted, so you do not pass that portion to `TIdHTTP` at all.

The part of the curl command between single quotes is the actual data to post.  `--data-urlencode` tells curl to send the data using the HTTP `POST` method, using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type, and url-encoding the data.

The `TStrings` version of `TIdHTTP.Post()` does all of that.  Normally, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is used with "name=value" string pairs, however there is no name being specified in the curl command, only a value.  If curl supplies a default name, then the Delphi code would look like this:

```
procedure TfrmMain.get1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  json: string;
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  lParamList: TStringList;
  result:string;
begin
  json := CRLF +
          '{' + CRLF +
          ' "resource_id": "391792b5-9c0a-48a1-918f-2ee63caa1c54",' + CRLF +
          ' "filters": {' + CRLF +
          '   "provider_id": 393303' + CRLF +
          ' }' + CRLF +
          '}';
  lParamList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    lParamList.Add('somename='+json);
    lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    try
      Result := lHTTP.Post('http://hub.Healthdata.gov/api/action/datastore_search', lParamList);
    finally
      lHTTP.Free;
    end;
  finally
    lParamList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Otherwise, if curl sends the specified data as-is by itself, then the Delphi code would look like this instead:

```
procedure TfrmMain.get1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  json: string;
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  lParamList: TStringList;
  result:string;
begin
  json := CRLF +
          '{' + CRLF +
          ' "resource_id": "391792b5-9c0a-48a1-918f-2ee63caa1c54",' + CRLF +
          ' "filters": {' + CRLF +
          '   "provider_id": 393303' + CRLF +
          ' }' + CRLF +
          '}';
  lParamList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    lParamList.Add(json);
    lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    try
      Result := lHTTP.Post('http://hub.Healthdata.gov/api/action/datastore_search', lParamList);
    finally
      lHTTP.Free;
    end;
  finally
    lParamList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The only difference being what parameter value gets passed to `TStringList.Add()`.

Answer (score 1):

They are not URL parameters it's part of the `POST` body that's just URL encoded.

You need to encode the JSON string and write it to a stream, perhaps `TMemoryStream` and then call:

```
TIdHTTP.Post(url,stream);
```